# What is CouchDB

Tags: mysql, couchdb

So what is couchDB exactly? taking out all the fancy technical terms.

Is it an alternative to MySQL basically?

Thanks

Comment: Google. If you don't find an answer, google again, because there are numerous descriptions of CouchDB from various angles lying about all over the web.

Comment: I must agree to Tom. There is a lot of information and really good documentation on CouchDB out in the interweb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, in MySQL you store rows and tables. In CouchDB you store documents (which can be also describes as rows and tables, but lets get to the highest abstraction level). It isn't alternative to MySQL, as it it designed for different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) site,  it's a documented oriented database. I think that it is not mean to replace MySQL. You can check this post [When to use CouchDB vs RDBMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307100/when-to-use-couchdb-vs-rdbms) for a analisis of the RDBMS vs NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that couchDB is document based, not table based, but I suggest reading more on their site.

The [introduction](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/intro.html) section at the couchDB site is pretty easy to read: